# Object.values contain a certain text

Tags: javascript

I have an object and I am trying to find a certain text inside the values of the object. How come exist variable below is false? But "text1" is part of "text1w".

```js
var obj = {
  "a": "test1w",
  "b": "test2"
}

let exist = Object.values(obj).includes("test1");
console.log(exist)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check each string and exit if found.

```js
var obj = { a: "test1w", b: "test2" },
    exist = Object.values(obj).some(s => s.includes("test1"));

console.log(exist);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) use [`samevalueZero`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Same-value-zero_equality) algorithm to check existence of value

So you can use [`String.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) by looping over each value which find the substring inside a string or use search

```js
var obj = {
  "a": "test1w",
  "b": "test2"
}

let exist = Object.values(obj).some(v=> v.search('test1'))
console.log(exist)
```